# Unable to record with http proxy server in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter and am using jmeter 2.9.

I am having a WIFI connectivity and I am using "Automatically detect settings" in browser. As part of jmeter I am changing that option and am entering proxy server as "localhost" and port as 8080( same as in jmeter http proxy server value). But with this setting no pages are getting loaded and jmeter is not recording.

Please suggest how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sitting behind corporate proxy. JMeter is not able to automatically detect proxy settings to you need to configure it to use the proxy as well. Here are available parameters:

```
    -H, --proxyHost <argument>
            Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
    -P, --proxyPort <argument>
            Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
    -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
            Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
    -u, --username <argument>
            Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
    -a, --password <argument>
            Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
```

See [Using JMeter behing a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) guide for additional information.

There is another option: [JMeter Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) which doesn't require any extra proxy configuration and you can record tests right from the browser.

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Thanks a lot. I am not behind any corporate proxy. By default I do not have any proxy mentioned in by browser, As i give localhost as proxy server I am unable to connect to the desired pages at all. Is there any way in which I can handle this situation without using an add - in,